# Why unexpected ' ' at the end while printing read file in python 3?

Tags: list, file-io, python-3.x

I am reading a simple text file and printing it as a list in python, so i run a while loop like this:

```
while line != "":
        line = file_ob.readline().strip()
        genres.append(line)
```

Everything works perfectly fine, but then at the end, `""` is also printed.

My question is why is this happening? Since line equals `""` or so to speak has reached the end of text file, isn't the loop supposed to break and display output without the `""`? is there perhaps a flaw with my logic here? How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop won't break in the middle automagically; it will run to the bottom, then return to the top to check the condition again. Thus, you read the empty line, append it, check if it is empty, then break. If you want to exclude the last line, it is commonly written like this:

```
while (line = file_ob.readline().strip()) != "":
    genres.append(line)
```

(EDIT: As OP notes, this is not valid syntax in Python, since assignment is not an expression, unlike in most other languages.)

or this:

```
line = file_ob.readline().strip()
while line != "":
    genres.append(line)
    line = file_ob.readline().strip()
```

Actually, neither of these is quite equal to your code, since at the beginning you don't show how `line` is defined. This would work too:

```
while True:
    line = file_ob.readline().strip()
    if line == "":
        break
    genres.append(line)
```

Comment: u see, i have to add a line first saying line = 'anything' to make the loop work. if i use the second option, the list contains 'anything' which i don't want. the first option doesn't seem to work.

Comment: a much easier solution is to read a line first and the assign it to line instead of 'anything'. it has worked thanks for the help

Comment: Ah, indeed, first option does not work, silly Python (and silly me thinking it behaves like other things I am used to). The second option will work without `line = "anything"`.